# Wordpress permalink adding "/" before index gate

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, permalinks

I am having some trouble with wordpress and its permalink system. I need to change how it automatically adds a "/" character before its $_GET variables in the permalink section.

I am using an mvc pattern and require all $_GET requests go through the index gate to be validated before allowing it to be used and change the page. All should be fine but when a url looks like anything.com/index.php/?var=blah breaks the page and I get console errors mentioning I have an unexpected ">" in all my javascript files being called. If I go into the url bar and remove the "/" after index like so anything.com/index.php?var=blah the page loads like normal.

I need to fix the permalinks so each custom post type and tax all lead to index.php? not index.php/?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code or *specific* error message? Like maybe you could track down where the erroneous `>` is?

Comment: the error message isnt the problem i believe. since I have noticed this behavior on other sites that include a "/" before GET vars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink

If you know how to work with wordpress hooks, this would be the filter you're looking for to alter the behavior of the permalinks.

Comment: hmm I saw this but thought it only affects the_permalink function which i am not using. I am using a wp_query search with return objs and referencing things like url via the default class members. i will look up your reference a bit more to see if i can use it.

Comment: I can't think of another wordpress function that could be useful here. Have you considered using mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL to what you need it to be?

Comment: I have but i didnt think that was a good solution since it relies so heavily on the apache doing the work. Plus it wont easily or quickly allow me to program and test on my local wamp. I was saving the rewrites for once it goes live just to prettify.

Comment: In looking further into the codex for add_query_args i see that it mostly does appending but i just need to backspace one character lol. The stupid "/" is ruining everything.

Comment: add_filter('the_permalink', 'callback_function');
    callback_function($url){ //regex here }

I would do something like that, and just use regex to remove the / after .php if there is a ? following it. The $url in that function will be the permalink.

Comment: Ya I have now spent an hour trying to avoid regex, php str functions and or unreliable string parsing that might hiccup but your right. Time to move on lol. Appreciate the help regardless

Answer (score 0):

Normally I don't answer my own questions but I thought it neccessary here. To anyone else who has a momentary lapse in brain power as well... this problem was solved by removing the "index.php" from my permalinks tab in wordpress admin panel. It required no extra code at all lol.

So now the urls show up like anything.com/?var=blah without the index.php and the pages load fine since the index is implied at the "/" root anyway. When I was getting anything.com/index.php/?var=blah it seems to have been trying to find a sub directory within the index file itself.